# How to bind a property inside a class inside another singleton?

Tags: wpf, xaml, bind

I have the following classes, for example:

```
public FatherClass
{
    // This is a singleton, with instance property named Instance

    public static ChildClass PropertyName { get; set; }
}

public ChildClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Using WPF in the XAML, how is it possible to bind a Label to this variable Name? I was able to do it with two levels (i.e, Father.Name), but I get errors everytime I try to do it with 3 levels, as the example shows.

What I have done was:

```
Label="{Binding Source=namespace:FatherClass.Instance.PropertyName, Path=Name}"
```

But this does not work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just bind directly to the static property:

```
{x:Static namespace:FatherClass.PropertyName.Name}
```

Comment: It is not possible. There is no instance ChildClass, only inside FatherClass. Therefore, it is impossible to directly access it as you said. ChildClass is not static.

Comment: @jpnavarini: Wrong.  Since `Name` is static, there is no instance involved.

Comment: I am sorry, it is not static, only FatherClass is static. I will edit the original post.

Comment: Then just reference the nested property.

Comment: This just doesn't work. As I said in the question, when I try to do it with 2 levels: FatherClass.Property it works, but when I have to do Father.ChildProp.Property, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Not till the point of class in a singleton(as in Question) but Property of child type in a singleton i am using. namespace:Common.DeviceModel
Singleton class: ConnectionStatusManager  //FatherClass of Question
ChildClass :   ConnectionStatus           //ChildClass of Question
property in that singleton: Status
in VM:

```
namespace Common.DeviceModel
{
 public class ConnectionStatusManager : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
      public static ConnectionStatusManager Instance...;
      public static ConnectionStatus Status...;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
xmlns:DeviceModel="clr-namespace:Common.DeviceModel;assembly=Common"
```

Uses:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static Member=DeviceModel:ConnectionStatusManager.Instance}, Path=Status}"  
                                             Value="{x:Static Member=DeviceModel:ConnectionStatus.DisConnected}">
                                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                                            </DataTrigger>
```